# Not able to return a view for [HttpPost] method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I get the following error when returning a view:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The view 'student' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Student/student.aspx
~/Views/Student/student.ascx
~/Views/Shared/student.aspx
~/Views/Shared/student.ascx
```

Here is my controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitStudent()
    {
        StudentViewModel model = TempData["model"] as StudentResponseViewModel;

        ViewData["id"] = model.Id;
        ViewData["name"] = model.Name;

        string comment = Request["comment"];

        var student = student.studentTable.Where(s => s.studentId == model.Id);

        return View(student);
    }
```

Here is my View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<string>>" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Student</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
Student name listed below:
</div>

<table>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
     <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item)%>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you actually POSTing something to `/Student/SubmitStudent`.  Methinks we're missing something.

Comment: Please provide your submit button/link information.

Comment: Sorry, here it is:

<div>
    
    <form method="post" action="/Student/SubmitStudent">
  
    <label for="comment">Comments : </label><br />
    <textarea name="comment" cols="20" rows="15">
    Enter your comments here...
    </textarea><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Student" />
    </form>

    </div>

Comment: @mootinator: Yes we are posting something to /Student/SubmitStudent through a webformt textarea on submit

Answer (score 2):

A few things to consider here.

First of all, returning a view after a HTTP POST is really a bad design choiche. You can google about the PRG Pattern and you will find many articles that will explain why you should always redirect to a HTTP GET which will render your view.

Second, I find strange that your code is looking for a view name "student". As per MVC specification, the controller will look for a view named as the action method unless an overload of the View() method which accepts the view name as parameter is called (which is not your case, at least not in the code you posted).

In your example, it seems like it should look for a view named "SubmitStudent". Again, the model type you declare on your view doesn't match the model you're passing to it. It accepts an `IEnumerable<string>` but you're passing to it an `IQueryable<Student>` (that's what your student variable contains).

I think you omitted some parts of your code. The parts you posted don't quite match with one another.

Comment: Ok, I am redirecting the view to a [HttpGet] method to render my view, how do I display the parameters from the [HttpPost] mehod SubmitStudent to the [HttpGet] method DisplayStudent?

Comment: Is this a good way of doing this? 

`[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult SubmitStudent() 
{ 
StudentViewModel model = TempData["model"] as StudentResponseViewModel; TempData["id"] = model.Id; 
TempData["name"] = model.Name; 
return RedirectToAction("DisplayStudent"); 
}`

`[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult DisplayStudent() 
{ 
ViewData["id"] = TempData["id"]; 
ViewData["name"] = TempData["name"]; 
return View(); 
}`

Comment: View:

`<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>


<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>DisplayStudent</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
             <%= ViewData["id"]%> <br />
             <%= ViewData["name"]%>
   
    </div>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Code posted in comments is hardly readable. Anyway, there's an interesting actionfilter in MvcContrib project that helps with the PRG pattern. It's called "ModelStateToTempData" and it basically, in case of validation error, serialize your modelstate into the tempdata during your post action, and automatically deserialize it back in the next GET method.

Answer (score 1):

Your view must be in `"Views\Student\"` - unless you have changed the view engine settings which I imagine you have not.

So I believe your view is not there.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your code to work, you're going to need a view called `SubmitStudent.aspx` inside the `Views\Student\` or `Views\Shared\` folders.

It also looks odd that your view inherits a list of strings and not a `Student` object or whatever type of object your query returns. Your view is expecting an enumerable list of `string`'s

This line is also confusing:

```
var student = student.studentTable.Where(s => s.studentId == model.Id);
```

Did you mean:

```
var student = model.studentTable.Where(s => s.studentId == model.Id);
```