# ASP.NET Core MVC : HTTP POST method not return to view

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("bolumler", null,  "lutfen bolum secin", 
                   new {@class = "form-control", 
                   @onchange="SelectedIndexChanged(this)"})

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectedIndexChanged(item) {

    var value = item.value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("GoTo")",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data:JSON.stringify( value ),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoTo([FromBody] string d)
{
    var personeller = await _iluPersonelService.getPersonelWithDepartment(d);

    List<SelectListItem> valuesForPersonel = (from x in personeller
                                              select new SelectListItem
                                                  {
                                                      Text = x.Name,
                                                  }).ToList();

    ViewBag.personeller = valuesForPersonel;

    return View();
}
```

I can't figure out this problem. In `.cshtml` side, I change dropdownlist selection item and controller post method triggering. I did some operations on the data and I want to return new data to view and display it.

Note: there are no changes on the page and it is not refreshed

Comment: Could you share your code of the view?

Comment: i added view section

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681444/not-able-to-return-a-view-for-httppost-method Please View this Post this would help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to  alert(data) ?
If so , do you want the below way ?

1. change the action like below:

   ```
        [HttpPost]    
        public async Task<IActionResult> GoTo([FromBody] string d)
        {  
         ...  
        return Json(valuesForPersonel);
        }
       public IActionResult Goto()
      {
        return View();
      }
   ```

2.In the view:
change the success method code in your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("GoTo")",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(value),
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                alert(data[i].text);
              window.location.href = "https://localhost:7169/RtCd/Goto";
        }},
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }


    });
```

result:

[image]

Comment: @Duhan Uzun Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: No, i cannot redirect to "GoTo" view for  httpost method. That's my main problem.

Comment: @Duhan Uzun      What do you mean "cannot redirect to "GoTo" view for httpost method" ? You have said "i change dropdownlist selection item and controller post method triggering." so the -view--  `@Html.DropDownList`  in which view?

Comment: @Html.DropDownList inside the index view.  i change dropdownlist selection item and this is triggering "GoTo" httpost method in the controller. but GoTo httpost method cannot return view. so the GoTo page won't load.  i want redirect GoTo page after GoTo httpost method

Comment: @DuhanUzun Please see my update, if you want to redirect GoTo page after GoTo httpost method , you need to use `window.location.href ` to go to an action, in that action you can go to the GoTo page . Or ajax is allowing websites to load content onto the screen without refreshing the page. With Ajax, web applications can send and retrieve data from a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behaviour of the existing page. So still in the index view.

Comment: thanks, i understand you. Can you send us one of your contact details so that we can stay in touch?

Comment: @DuhanUzun Sorry, I am afraid I can't  because of the forum rule. You can put your question in the form, we all will help you. Thanks .